# fractions in binary and hex

Tags: floating-point, binary, hex

Is there any language that can handle non decimal floating point numbers the same way they can with integers.  The following happens in python, javascript, elixir...

```
>>> 0b11
3
>>> 0b11 + 0b11
6
>>> 0b1.1
Some kind of Syntax Error
>>> 0b1.1 + 0b1.1
Some kind of Syntax Error
```

I want to see

```
>>> 0b1.1
1.5
>>> 0b1.1 + 0b1.1
3
```

(This might break the recommend a tool rule, but I don't see how it could especially attract opinionated answers so going for it; might delete it if people are offended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C has hexadecimal floating-point constants in the form `0x` *hexadecimal-digits* `.` *hexadecimal-digits* `p` *sign*<sub>optional</sub> *decimal-digits*, where the digits before or after the `.` are optional, but one must be present. For example, `0x7.afp4`. The `p` and *decimal-digits* specify a power of two, which the hexadecimal portion is multiplied by.

Comment: thanks `printf ("%f\n", 0x1.8p0 + 0x1.8p0)` worked as I hoped!